# Not inserting into database sql read error

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?
include("../../panel/inc/config.php");

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Insert the log
$insert = "INSERT INTO logs (log, ip, date) VALUES ('{$log}', '{$ip}', '{$date}')";
mysql_query($insert) or die("MySQL Error - Could not insert reviews");

$date = date("d/m/y - h:ia");
$insertLog = "INSERT INTO `logs` ( `log` , `ip`, `date` ) VALUES ('viewed test page', '$date')";
mysql_query($insertLog) or die('MySQL Error - Could not insert a log.');
?>
```

basically when someone views this page, I want it to insert into the database, but it's not inserting. I get the Error for inserting log.

Any ideas?

My database is

[image]

Comment: @meda `MySQL Error - Could not insert a log.`

Comment: if you put  - `die(mysql_error())` you will get an error from the database

Answer (score 3):

```
$insertLog = "INSERT INTO `logs` ( `log` , `ip`, `date` ) VALUES ('viewed test page', '$date')";
```

missing one column value here. You have three columns but two values in above query. It seems that you have missed ip value in above query.

you should try like this:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(isset($ip)){

// Insert the log
    $insert = "INSERT INTO logs (log, ip, date) VALUES ('{$log}', '{$ip}', '{$date}')";
    mysql_query($insert) or die('MySQL Error - ' . mysql_error() );

    $date = date("d/m/y - h:ia");
    $insertLog = "INSERT INTO `logs` ( `log` , `ip`, `date` ) VALUES ('viewed test page','$ip' '$date')";
    mysql_query($insertLog) or die('MySQL Error - ' . mysql_error() );
    }
```

**notice:** all `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should move to [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: still gives me the `MySQL Error - Could not insert a log.` error

Comment: @TrippedStackers use `die('MySQL Error - ' . mysql_error() )` for display real MySQL error

Comment: I get `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` isa this because of the `id` field?